How to show y-axis nominal labels, regardless of whether there is data
I have some a simple bar chart, and at times some of the y-axis nominal categories do not have any data associated with them. However, I do still want to show these values on the chart, for consistency purposes. This is a simplified example:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Bar chart with text labels. Set domain to make the frame cover the labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": null},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": null},
      {"a": "E", "b": 20}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": "point"
  }]
}

It returns me this:

But I'd like to see the following:

I managed to do it by making them 0 and adding the following condition:
"opacity": {
   "condition":{"test": "datum['b'] == 0", "value": 0}, "value": 1
}

but wondering if there is a more elegant approach, especially as my use case is more complex and depends on dates, not numbers
Open the Chart in the Vega Editor

The problem is VL is generating an isValid filter in the underlying Vega. Your approach is fine. Here is an alternative:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Bar chart with text labels. Set domain to make the frame cover the labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": -1},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": -1},
      {"a": "E", "b": 20}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "scale":{"domainMin":0}}
  },
  "layer": [{ "mark":{"type": "point", "clip":true}  }]
}


ah, that could work in my more complex use case, can just add a date that's not within the x-axis domain as a default value. Not super elegant, but should definitely do the trick!
